# How to add Procfile in pycharm for Heroku deplyment?

Tags: django, heroku, pycharm

Trying to add a Procfile to my pycharm django project but it just asking me for the file extention. Any idea??

Comment: That file shouldn't have an extension. It's just named `Procfile`.

Comment: i have example deploy in heroku. It can simple like this : https://github.com/idontgotit/mysite/blob/master/Procfile

Answer (score 3):

Go to file > new file > type in Procfile > enter > select the type: file containing setting for the editor

Answer (score 1):

Give it the extension .txt, edit it and then refactor the file to be without an extension again.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, you first have to install the Heroku CLI.
Go to Deploy on your Heroku app page then go to "Download and install the Heroku CLI".
After downloading, restart Pycharm and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your venv is activated before you create a Procfile. You should be free to create it without an extension if the venv is activated.